# Using VBA in Word to find and format ordinal ranks with superscript

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, find, superscript

I am working in Microsoft Word and need VBA to find and format specific text as superscript. I am trying to format the following text as superscript, but only if the text immediately follows a number. Here's the four pieces of text I would need to find:

st
nd
rd
th

Here's an example:

*Bill was 1st in the race, but was followed closely by the second place finisher, Steve.*

After applying the code to this example, the "st" of 1st would be formatted as a superscript, but the "nd" in second would be untouched.

Below is the code I am working with, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
Sub ReplaceOrdinals()

ActiveDocument.Range.Select

Dim regExp As Object
Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With regExp
    .Pattern = "(?<=[0-9])[dhnrst]{2}"
    .Global = True
    Selection.Font.Superscript = wdToggle
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Word replaces these automatically as you type (there is a tick in the autoformat dialog). To apply this to existing text, select Autoformat from the menu and make sure the tick is set. To only apply this and not anything else, clear all other ticks except this one.

Comment: Thanks GSerg for the comment. The problem is that I have several pages of information pasted from excel. It takes several minutes to manually find all the occurrences. I repeat the process a dozen times per week so some code would be a huge time saver.

Comment: It takes two seconds to bring up the autoformat dialog and click Autoformat. All these will be replaced.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines about asking questions on the site. You'll see that a certain amount of research on the asker's part is expected, along with code they've tried and can't get to work. In order to stay within the guidelines I suggest you first take your question to an End-user forum, such as Super User here on StackExchange. Ask how to use Word's Find with wildcards feature to find what you want to look up. Once you have that working, record it in a macro - this will give you the code starting point. Then you can ask here how to modify it :-)

Comment: @Cin While Word allows you to apply formatting when replacing things with regular expressions, the formatting has to be applied to the entire match. Because of this, the regular expression would need to contain a positive lookbehind to exclude the number itself from applying the superscript, and Word does not support zero-length assertions. A macro is possible, but would have to be written manually and involve use of an external regex library, finding the position of a match in `Range.Text` and converting the position back to `Range` to apply superscript (quite inefficient). +1 otherwise.

Comment: @gserg I'm not suggesting regex, which is not "native" to Word or to VBA. A macro based on Word's internal Find can build a solid basis, if the OP wants a macro. It's up to the OP. But if code is not used then the question is off-topic on SO... Personally, I think long and hard before even considering AutoFormat because I simply do not trust it - but that's me and 25 years of "taming" Word :-)

Comment: @gserg Thanks for the comments. I have not had success with applying autoformat to existing text. Only to text that I will type. If i change it after pasting the unformatted text into the document, nothing changes. Of course, I can simply delete the last couple characters of the ordinal rank and retype the characters, calling on the autoformat to then produce the desired result, but this is not ideal with the amount of text I am working with. I hope this helps to explain my conundrum.

Comment: @Cin Thanks Cindy for the thoughts. Optimizing code produced from recording a macro was my first idea, yet I didn't find success with this. Specifically, I was not able to find and select only the last two characters of the word. Finding the whole word was easy, but I only want to reformat the last two characters as superscript. Word's limitations with using regex seemed to be the hurdle for me. Take, for example, the postive lookbehind assertion (?<=[0-9])th which should match the last two characters of "9th" but not the "9". This does not work in Word for reasons that GSerg specified.

Comment: @GSerg I have now edited my original question so that it contains the code I am now working with.

Comment: That's correct, it can't be done with Find/Replace alone - Find must be combined with macro code. If you have the code that finds the entire word that would be a good starting point. You cannot use RegEx, it needs to be Word's wild cards. The reason is that Find works directly with the Word content, including formatting. RegEx can only work independently of the in-place content, which means no formatting. Substitute the successful Find code in your question for the RegEx and I can show you how to modify it.

Comment: @enstmagoo You don't simply change the setting to make it work. You actually invoke the autoformat command that reformats the entire document, and you make sure only the relevant ticks are allowed in its settings before committing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Private Function SuperscriptAll(ByVal where As Range, ByVal pattern As String, ByVal wildcards As Boolean)
  Dim true_end As Long
  true_end = where.End

  With where.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .ClearAllFuzzyOptions

    Do While .Execute(pattern, MatchWildcards:=wildcards, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop)
      With .Parent
        .MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
        .Font.Superscript = True
        .SetRange .End, true_end
      End With
    Loop
  End With
End Function

Public Sub ReplaceOrdinals()
  SuperscriptAll ActiveDocument.Range, "1st", False
  SuperscriptAll ActiveDocument.Range, "2nd", False
  SuperscriptAll ActiveDocument.Range, "3rd", False
  SuperscriptAll ActiveDocument.Range, "[0-9]th", True
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a dream. Thanks so much, I really appreciate it.